# Installing WordPress Plugin Running on Google Appengine SDK

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have installed WordPress 3.5.1 running on Google Appengine version 1.8.1 SDK. Note, I have ubuntu 12.04. WordPress works fine; I create posts, upload images etc.
My problem is as follow:

**I can activate and deactivate plugins but the admin panel doesn't give me the option to add new plugin.**

I figured out that in order to install plugins, i have to go to the

```
http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/plugin-install.php
```

. But when i get there I recieve the following message:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I have figured out that this problem has to do with the admin role.

Explored my Database...I went to `wp_usermeta` table -> looked at the column `meta_key` with the row of `wp_capabilities`. The `meta_value` is `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`. Also the `wp_user_level` value is `10`. Note that the `user_id` is `1` which is the user_id of the administrator.

Also I went to the `wp_options` table -> looked at the column `option_name` with the row of `wp_user_roles`. The `option_value` is

```
a:5:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:62:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s:14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;s:11:"update_core";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:12:"remove_users";b:1;s:9:"add_users";b:1;s:13:"promote_users";b:1;s:18:"edit_theme_options";b:1;s:13:"delete_themes";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;}}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:34:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;}}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:10:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;}}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}}
```

In order to see if there is any problem with WordPress 3.5.1. I installed Apache server and tested the WordPress there. Everything works just fine and I am able to install plugins from the admin panel.
I think this problem has to do with Appengine SDK. For now I install the plugins manually by uploading it to the `wp-content/plugins` folder...

Has anyone been able to install plugins through admin panel of the WordPress 3.5.1 running on Appengine SDK?

Comment: How are you accessing the wp-content/plugins folder on the app engine deployment? I have plugins installed locally but they are not available when I deploy to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is blocked by the Google App Engine plugin. I don't think it would be easily possible to do this. your best bet is to download plugins to your local environment then run appcfg.py update - but I may be wrong and would love an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

The Google App Engine filesystem is not writable. In order to install WordPress plugins, you have to add them to your `plugins` folder locally and then deploy your application using `appcfg.py` or `gcloud`. Once deployed, you can go to the plugins page and activate them.

> **Note**: You'll want to keep that local copy of WordPress handy, because you'll need it to install custom themes and plugins. Because of the security sandbox, your live WordPress site can not write to the local files -- they're static. This means the auto-installation of themes and plugins in the WordPress dashboard will only work in the local WordPress that you run on your own machine. So, remember to do all your installing locally, then re-deploy your WordPress app.[1]

[1] https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/